# Optical character recoginition

Tags: artificial-intelligence, pattern-recognition, backpropagation

I've to write a program which is able to recognize patterns, specially characters. I've implemented back-propagation in c# and now I want to use it for the pattern recognition. I've also created a form application and used brush/graphics so that user can write something with the help of mouse (just like 'pencil tool' in MS Paint). So I need some helping material about "How to implement character recognition method in my application?".

Helping stuff over the internet mostly related to back-propagation and software demos.

Answer (score 1):

If your project is something else but you want to have OCR in your project, you should search for third party tools that do this. But if your project is this and you want to do that yourself, read this answer:

There are two ways of recognizing characters. Online and offline.

Online way uses the pen (or mouse) input data. and offline way uses just the pixels.

Your first step will be choose from one of them. offline way hasn't the pen data, this is a useful feature. but in offline, you can recognize characters from image files (created by paint and saved or even scanned)

Second, you should preprocess data (this step is for only offline way). you should remove noises from it, scale it, and do the Thinning to it.

Next, you should extract useful features from the preprocessed data (online or offline). for this, you can read some articles about optical character recognition and feature extractions of it. there is a good powerpoint presentation *about preprocessing and feature extraction* [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=optical%20character%20recognition%20filetype%3appt&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://www.iit.demokritos.gr/IIT_SS/Presentations/Off-Line%2520Handwritten%2520OCR.ppt&ei=-RMGT5u5DcbD8QOg-tCxAQ&usg=AFQjCNHN_jijSFqHbQrlMfRi6vGEBPyxoQ). Also `pdf` keyword and `filetype:pdf` at the end of your search term in google would help you!

Then you should use neural networks or something like that to recognize the character. inputs should be extracted features.

But remember, this project is not easy and may take some time! (This was my project for Persian language)

Comment: I see no absolute need for feature extraction.  With a backprop network, the input layer might simply be one neuron per input pixel.

Comment: @Novak Maybe true. but you will need a very large and GOOD input set. because even one wrong character or bad noises can make terrible training. And that will be sensitive to position and size. I suggest to use features (even simple , like projection histograms) and extract images from preproccessed image. because it can increase the detection rate...

Comment: Agreed.  It wasn't clear if the original poster was looking for performance, or was just self-teaching.